# installing software policy without password

Tags: software-center, password, policykit

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS, There are two accounts one with administrator privileged, the second is the standard one(without password)

I created a new file called:

```
10-allow-users-to-install.pkla
```

and copied to:

```
/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/
```

The rules I added are:

```
[Untrusted Install]
Identity=unix-user:majd
Action=org.debian.apt.install-or-remove-packages
ResultAny=no
ResultInactive=no
ResultActive=yes

[Untrusted Update]
Identity=unix-user:majd
Action=org.debian.apt.update-cache
ResultAny=no
ResultInactive=no
ResultActive=yes

[snapcraft]
Identity=unix-user:majd
Action=io.snapcraft.snapd.manage
ResultAny=no
ResultInactive=no
ResultActive=yes
```

majd is the name of the standard account.

The problem is I'm able to download apps from the software center only when the source of the apps is **Snape Store** but when the source is one of the following (ubuntu-bionic-universe,ubuntu-bionic-main, or ubuntu-bionic-multiverse) it requires the administrator's password.

Note: The second account is automatically logged in without a password (there's no password for this account).

I tried to reboot the system many times, and change the presmissions of *10-allow-users-to-install.pkla* file to:

```
  -rw-r--r--
```

but still didn't working.

How can I download apps from software center from any source without the administrator password?